# How do I post an array to a different worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

So I am creating a piece of code that moves a line of data to a different worksheet with the value in a box column I turns to '7 - Engaged'

Everything up until the highlighted code (shown above) works well.

I thought that if I turned the line of data into an array it would be easier to then post this to the next sheet.

The code I am using below now comes up with a Run-time error 438: Compile Error, Expected: I dentifier or Bracketed.

The thing is I cannot define which row of data this will be as it will depend on which row the change was made to the I Column.

Additionally I want the data to be posted to the first empty row in the next sheet -'Tank'

I have tried moving each cell individually using Offset and PasteSpecial, but this is clunky at the best of times and has caused issues of its own.

Should I carry on using a transposed array and how do I paste the array variables to another sheet
[image]

```
Dim myRange As Range

For Each myRange In Range("I6:I1000")

Select Case myRange.Value
Case "7 - engaged"
VBA.Interaction.MsgBox "Client status selected as engaged. Confirm to post to tank", 1, "Status Change"

myArr = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Range("A:M")))

Sheets("Tank").(BlankRow = Range("B1000").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
ActiveSheet.Range("A:M") = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr)




End Select

Next myRange

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I'm guessing your question got downvoted because you posted a screenshot of code rather than actual code.  That makes it exceptionally difficult for people to help out and troubleshoot your problem.  Please swap out the image with the actual code, and that will make it much easier for people to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're after something like the code below.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Source As Range)
    ' Maybe disable events whilst this code runs (and re-enable before exit)
    ' to prevent recursion.

    If Source.Column <> 9 Then Exit Sub ' 9 = I
    If Source.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub ' Check this first before making comparison on next line
    If Source.Value <> "7 - engaged" Then Exit Sub

    If MsgBox("Client status selected as engaged. Confirm to post to tank.", vbOKCancel) = vbOK Then
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tank")
            Dim rowToPasteTo As Long
            rowToPasteTo = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1

            .Range("A" & rowToPasteTo & ":" & "M" & rowToPasteTo).Value = Sh.Range("A" & Source.Row & ":" & "M" & Source.Row).Value
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

It's good to put `Option Explicit` before your code. Seems like you assigned `myArr` but transposed `arr` in your code. Assuming these weren't global variables, `Option Explicit` can catch such issues. There were also some syntax and member/attribute errors.

Comment: Apologies for not adding in the code yesterday, I was tired and didn't thinks